# Не могу понять поведение библиотеки ReactiveUI ver 7?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
  public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private string _message;
    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return _message;
        }
        set
        {
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _message, value);
        }
    }

    public ReactiveCommand Click { get; }
    private int it;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        it = 0;
        Click = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () =>
        {
             await Task.Delay(5000);
             Interlocked.Increment(ref it);
             Message = $"Hello Reactive {it}";
        }); 

    }
}
```

Написал такой небольшой кусок кода, чтобы проверить функционал, столкнулся с некоторым недопониманием: в текущем варианте при вызове команды Click по кнопке весь интерфейс лочится, а потом выводится сообщение, хотя мне казалось что код должен выполняться асинхронно, если заменяю на метод Create то интерфейс не лочится и сообщение выводится через 5сек, но тут возникает другая фишка, если я несколько раз кликну по кнопке, то переменная it инкрементируется несколько раз, что мне тоже кажется странным, ибо гуглив, я читал что здесь есть защита от множественного вызова? 
Так вот вопрос: я что то не так понимаю в работе библиотеки или в новой версии что то не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Библиотека работает правильно, была ошибка в разметке тестовой формы